# Execute a batch script from Firefox

Tags: security, firefox, rdp

I have written an intranet application from which you can directly connect to a virtual machine by clicking on a RDP-button. The click calls a .bat file, which opens the connection.

With IE, this is no problem, as you can choose to directly execute the batch file. But with Firefox, I can only download the script, and have to start it manually afterwards. Is there a way to trust the intranet domain (about:config?) so Firefox allows it to execute scripts directly? Or is there an even better (easier) way to start an RDP connection from Firefox?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can easily [register a custom protocol handler](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa767914%28VS.85%29.aspx) such as "`myrdp://somedata`" to run the app that opens the VM (This would probably work with a .bat, it works with a WSH script, better a small exe)
IE/FF support this functionality and allow you to then simply `<a href="myrdp://somedata" ..>`

Answer (score 2):

You could also try to set up your firefox to automatically open the .rdp files with the default rdp client. This way the files will be downloaded in a temp dir and immediately started up.

You can do this in Firefox's preferences. Hope this helps )

Comment: Ah, didn't think of that. Just for the record: It's also possible to add this capability by editing the `mimeTypes.rdf` file in your Firefox profile folder.

Comment: You didn't come across any really good resources on this, did you?  I'm doing something similar.  I've successfully built the RDF file but cannot seem to prevent it from prompting the user.